# Passing a multidimensional array

Tags: c, c99

I know that for 1-dimensional arrays, I can do...

```
void g(int x[]) {}

void f(int a, int b)
{
    int x[a];
    g(x);
}
```

But with code such as...

```
void f(int a, int b)
{
    int x[a][b][4];
    g(x);
}
```

What would the type signature of g(x) look like?

Comment: Your code won't compile. You cannot have a variable as an array length.

Comment: This is C, not C90. It complies on any modern compiler. You might need the -std=c99 flag on gcc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void g(int x[][b][4]) // b must be known in advance
{}
```

Otherwise explicitly pass `b`

For example:

```
void g(int b,int x[][b][4]){ 

} 

int main() 
{ 
    int a=4,b=6; 
    int x[a][b][4]; 
    g(b,x); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Oh, I can pass in b? That changes everything. Thanks!

Comment: Note how within the function `g()`, the value of `sizeof x[0]` depends upon the passed value of `b`, and may be different from one invocation of the function to the next.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the sizes of the arrays:

```
void g(int x[][2][3]){ 
    /* stuff */
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int x[1][2][3]; 
    g(x); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Clang:

there.c:185:43: warning: incompatible pointer types passing '_Bool [problem.gridSize.x + 1][problem.gridSize.y + 1][4]' to parameter of type '_Bool ***'

Comment: that doesn't follow the format. 1 and 2 aren't known in advance. They are variables. It MUST be [a][b].

Comment: I'm not familiar with your compiler, sorry. You might want to consider doing these as pointers to dynamic memory. Then you wouldn't have to worry about not knowing them in advance.